# Lots of Error because of header files

Tags: c

I am getting these errors in my code. I am sure these are just because of some single mistake, but I am unable to find it. Please help me!

```
2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(15): error C2065: 'node' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(15): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(26): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(29): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(29): error C3861: 'createQueue': identifier not found
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(35): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(38): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(38): error C3861: 'addFront': identifier not found
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(45): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(45): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(45): error C3861: 'dQueue': identifier not found
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(48): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(48): error C3861: 'destroyList': identifier not found
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(52): error C2065: 'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\omer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\firstnamelastname\firstnamelastname\testing.cpp(52): error C3861: 'printList': identifier not found
```

Below are Three Files
File 1 >> testing.cpp

```
//#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"
#include "linklist.h"
#include"stdafx.h"

int main(void)
{   
    int x,n;
    int number;
    int i;

    node *linked_list2= NULL;


        while (1) 
        {           
            printf("1.)To create Queue\n2.)To nQueue\n3.)To dQueue\n4.)To Destroy Queue\n5.)To Print The Queue\n6.)Exit Program\nPrint Your Choice: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);

            switch (n) /*Switch statement for testing of different functions*/
            {
                case 1:
                    if(linked_list2 == NULL){
                        printf("Enter Value Please\n");
                        scanf("%d",&number);
                        linked_list2=createQueue(number);
                    }
                    else
                        printf("Queue already created\n.");
                break;
                case 2:
                    if(linked_list2 != NULL){
                        printf("Give a no. to add: ");
                        scanf("%d",&number);
                        addFront(linked_list2,number);
                    }
                    else
                        printf("Create Link List First\n.");

                break;
                case 3:
                    linked_list2=dQueue(linked_list2);
                break;
                case 4:
                    destroyList(linked_list2);
                printf("List is Empty!! So Exiting Program! Bye!!\n");   /*Exits program after the list is emptied*/
                break;
                case 5:
                printList(linked_list2);
                break;
                case 6:
                printf("Exiting Program");
                return 0;
                break;
                default:
                printf("Wrong Input!!! Please Input Again: ");        /*asks to input the choice again if its incorrect*/
                scanf("%d",&n);

            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

File 2 >> queue.h

```
#include"linklist.h"

node * dQueue(node *num)   /*Deletes the value of the node from the front*/
{
    //num = num->next;  
    return (num->next);
}


void nQueue (node *head, int num ) /*Adds node to the front of Linked-List*/
{
    addFront(head,num);
}

node* createQueue(int val){

    return createList(val);
}
```

File 3 >> linklist.h

```
struct node{
    node * next;
    int nodeValue;
};

node* initNode(int number);
node* createList (int value);
void addFront (node *head, int num );
void deleteFront(node*num);
void destroyList(node *list);
int getValue(node *list);
void printList(node *list);
```

I have bodies of these function in `linklist.cpp`.

Comment: There is no C++ in this code.

Comment: cpp is a strange extension for C files ... but what do I know?

Comment: It will be Good if you answer my question =)

Comment: file1.c #includes file2.h and file3.h and file2.h includes file3.h; in file3.h shoud be an #ifndef __FILE3_H_INCLUDED #define __FILE3_H_INCLUDED ... #endif

Comment: I have a feeling I caused a havoc with my blind retag here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, declaring `struct foo` does not introduce a type called `foo`.

You need to:

- Say `struct node` wherever you say `node`,
- or add `typedef struct node node`.

Comment: did not get you sorry...

Comment: ...but unwinds answer is all you need: you declare an entity "struct node", but you use entities "node" (without the qualifier "struct"). you have two options: use "struct node" or typedef your "struct node" to "node"

Answer (score 1):

use typedef struct instead of only struct :

```
typedef struct _node{
  node * next;
  int nodeValue;
}node;
```

Comment: isn't "struct _node * next" more precise? with "node * next" you have a forward use.

Comment: @PeterMiehle Not only more precise, `error: unknown type name ‘node’`, even with default lenient gcc behaviour, it's required.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct _node{
    struct _node * next;
    int nodeValue;
} node;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
error C2065: 'node' : undeclared identifier
```

As it says: the identifier is undeclared. Unlike C++, C has separate namespaces for `struct`s and other stuff, so use

```
struct node * dQueue(node *num)
```

instead.

This is right. You should look where it is defined or what it is supposed to do.

```
'linked_list2' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'createQueue': identifier not found
error C3861: 'addFront': identifier not found
error C3861: 'dQueue': identifier not found
error C3861: 'destroyList': identifier not found
error C3861: 'printList': identifier not found
```

These all result from the lack of definition. Fix the first one and these errors will be gone as well.